# Not able to log into Linux server using Paramiko from Windows

Tags: python, linux, ssh, paramiko

Hi I am using a Windows Server 2008 R2 via Remote desktop.

My requirement is to log into a Linux machine and copy packages to Windows Server 2008 machine.

But in first stage only i am stuck, not able to log into the Linux server.
I have written the following code on Remote Desktop .

```
def Package_Copying(self,timeout=60):

    ssh=paramiko.SSHClient()

    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

    ssh.connect("10.82.110.9",timeout=70,username='XXXX',password='XXXXX',look_for_keys=False)



    ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command('ls -ltr')

    print "output",  ssh_stdout.read() 

    self.close()
```

When I am executing the same I am getting the below error.

```
"error: (10060, 'A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond')"
```

When i am doing the same from putty, i am able to logged in. but it will take 3 or 4 seconds to logged in.

Below is the Ping trace of the same server

```
C:\Users\Administrator>ping 10.82.110.9

Pinging 10.82.110.9 with 32 bytes of data:

Reply from 10.82.110.9: bytes=32 time=229ms TTL=234

Reply from 10.82.110.9: bytes=32 time=229ms TTL=234

Reply from 10.82.110.9: bytes=32 time=230ms TTL=234

Reply from 10.82.110.9: bytes=32 time=229ms TTL=234


Ping statistics for 10.82.110.9:

    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),

Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:

    Minimum = 229ms, Maximum = 230ms, Average = 229ms


C:\Users\Administrator>
```

Comment: Is the Linux server you are trying to connect to running a SSH server and can you connect? If you're unsure you could try to connect to the server using PuTTY from your Windows.

Comment: @vesche: original question already states PuTTY was tried. What it does not state, though, is whether a jump host of some kind is involved.

Comment: Yeah from Putty i am able to access..even i am able to do winscp from windows machine...only problem with that server is ..it is little bit slow in responding..means taking 2 seconds in connecting.
Could you please help me out to avoid this connection refused error ..thank you

Comment: I searched and came to know that in windows machine we have to increase timeout..but that option i am not able to find in windows server..need help

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar error when I set the incorrect port in paramiko, try adding the port flag :

```
 ssh.connect("10.82.110.9",port=22,timeout=70,username='XXXX',password='XXXXX',look_for_keys=False)
```